# Is there a known closed form sequence for algebraic number one-to-one with the natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory

We have a closed form recursive sequence for the rational numbers, where they appear only once. It is called the Calkin-Wilf sequence. Namely,

$q_{i+1}=\frac{1}{2⌊q_i⌋-q_i+1},q_1=1$.

Has someone found out an analog for algebraic numbers? I couldn't find any when searching but would be very surprised if one wasn't discovered already or serious public attempts were made to find one.

Comment: It doesn't quite do what you want, but you may be interested in the $j$-invariant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant

Comment: What is "closed form" supposed to mean precisely? How exactly is an algebraic number like the a root $\alpha$ of $x^5 - x - 1$ going to appear in such a list,  since, by Galois, $\alpha$ itself doesn't have any "closed form" expression in its most natural meaning?

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with trying to find an explicit list.

Firstly, the minimal irreducible polynomials, though clearly countable, can't be explicitly identified.

Secondly, even if you somehow managed to bypass that obstacle, the next issue is how to distinguish the conjugates.

Bottom line: It's a hopeless task, so I would just settle for a proof of countability (which is routine).

Comment: Maybe it's a hopeless task, but it's still a very good question!

Comment: Well, just the fact that there's no known closed form test for irreducibility of integer polynomials (there are algorithms, but no closed form condition) strongly supports the "hopeless" claim.

Comment: Sure, but what is "hopeless" to you might be "hard, unsolved and fascinating" to someone else.

Comment: Unsolved is a good bet. That no one is working on it is also a good bet. At least that's how I would bet.

Comment: I agree that, however doubtful, it's at least conceivable that a closed form list is possible. What I gave was heuristic support for the argument against the existence of such a closed form. As a suggestion, perhaps start with something simpler. How about just a closed form (not an algorithm) for listing all irreducible integer polynomials? Or even simpler, try it for irreducible polynomials mod $p$, for some fixed prime $p$, say $p=2$.

Comment: Since positive rationals are some of the algebraic integers of degree 1, I am going to see if I can generalize Calkin and Wilf's work to degree 2, 3... and see if there is a pattern in the formula.

Comment: A nontrivial quest, for sure. A closed-form bijection from the set of positive integers to the set of degree $2$ algebraic numbers would already be quite an accomplishment. Good luck!